# docker compose file is invalid ,additional properties not allowed tty

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I really need help on this error I don't understand why I  get this error. Thanks

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3
docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4
```

this is my dockerfile

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  arcgis-server:
    container_name: "arcgis-server"
    image: "arcgis-server:10.4.1"
    volumes:
      - "./license:/license"
      - "./arcgisserver:/arcgis/server/usr/directories"
      - "./config-store:/arcgis/server/usr/config-store"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 25059
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6080:6080"
      - "127.0.0.1:6443:6443"
      - "4001:4001"
      - "4002:4002"
      - "4004:4004"
    stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

here is the error

```
docker-compose build
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Additional properties are not allowed ('tty' was unexpected)

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version ("2.0", "2.1", "3.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

Actually I test on the old machine it worked fine. I would appreciate your helps. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2):

`tty` needs to be defined as a setting on your service, not at the top level. Yaml files are space sensitive, so removing the leading spaces puts the setting at the top level where it's not valid. Use the following syntax to fix it:

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  arcgis-server:
    container_name: "arcgis-server"
    image: "arcgis-server:10.4.1"
    volumes:
      - "./license:/license"
      - "./arcgisserver:/arcgis/server/usr/directories"
      - "./config-store:/arcgis/server/usr/config-store"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 25059
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6080:6080"
      - "127.0.0.1:6443:6443"
      - "4001:4001"
      - "4002:4002"
      - "4004:4004"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```